# Division of linear functions in convex polytope

Tags: convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I am a computer scientist, and find myself needing the following lemma:

If f(x)=(g(x))/(h(x)), where g and h are linear and positive with domain the convex polytope d, then extrema of f occur at vertices of d.

If that is not possible, the following would suffice:

If f(x)=(g(x))/(g(x)+h(x)), where g and h are linear and non-negative (and g + h is positive) with domain the convex polytope d, then extrema of f occur at vertices of d.

It seems that this is true. But I am having trouble proving it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The first lemma is correct (and therefore, so is the second). If $g$ and $h$ are linear and positive, then $g/h$ is convex, and thus the maxima of $g/h$ occur at vertices of $d$. The minima of $g/h$ are the reciprocals of the maxima of $h/g$, and thus occur at vertices of $d$ by a similar argument (using the convexity of $h/g$).